# Export Polygons from Service Area tool using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I have created a service area in ModelBuilder.

I have assigned a polygon to the "facilities".

How do I export the service area polygon to a shapefile in ModelBuilder?

Comment: Is it a feature layer? What is the service area at the moment? My first thought is Copy Features http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000 have a read of that and see how that goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Select Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000009000000) tool on the result of the Solve tool. It will allow you to get at what you need:

> The Select Data tool selects data in a parent data element such as a
>   folder, geodatabase, feature dataset, or coverage.
>
> The tool allows access to the data stored inside a parent container,
>   such as feature classes or tables inside a geodatabase.

([link to full-size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA8nx.png))

[image]

Comment: Also Feature class to Feature class (conversion) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000 all 3 do just about the same thing in a slightly different way. Nice pics though.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson you'll have to test that one out because I've tried everything else and even from ESRI network analyst developers told me to use 'select data'... let me know if you can get it to work!

Comment: Fair enough, I wont argue with the experts. Select Data (and Table Select) allows a definition query which makes that one mostly preferable; I generally use Copy Features unless I want to specify a query but that's so I know what's going on: Select Data means there's a query, Copy Features there's not.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson "select data" is different... its built to get into those special ArcGIS datasets... took me a few times to remember what the tool was!

Comment: This Q and a Related Q helped me a lot
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128152/modelbuilder-make-service-area-layer#