# Modelbuilder - make service area layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, time

I made a model in the model builder (ArcGis) to make a service area layer (see figure).

Now I want to run this tool for the same locations but for different hours.
-> the results would be a feature class for the location of the service areas at 6.00h, 
  the next output would be another feature class for the location of the service areas at 7.00h and so on... (from 6.00 AM until 22.00PM)

How can I change the time of day automatically and the name of each output file?

[image: model builder_service area]

Like mentioned in the first answer/ comment

I add the tool 'iterate field values' at my model
in the csv file are the different time periods in the format: 6:00:00  7:00:00 and so on..

Now, it's the problem that i don't understand how i can link the value to the tool 'make service area layer' in the field 'Time of Day (optional)

[image]

Comment: You will need to use an iterator that generates the time sequence you require then use in-line substitution for the time_of_day parameter. It is likely you need to build a master model with the iterator and your existing model becomes an embedded sub-model. Look at the advance section of model builder in the Help file.

Comment: thanks, but i problem to add the values with the different time periods at the tool 'make service area layer'...

Comment: The output of your iterator is _Value_ therefore you use in-line substitution in your time of day parameter. You would simply type %Value%.  With each loop of the iterator it passes out your time value and using %Value% is how you get it into the parameter.

Comment: owkey i get the idea after %Value%

But when i add %Value% in the field Time of day (optional) and click afterwards on the button OK
the text '%Vallue% just dissapear and the field is again empty.. looks me strange...

Comment: Sounds like a data format issue? According to the help file for that parameter, the data type is a Date. Maybe put your data into table into a Geodatabase and ensure the field is a Date field?